# Cauchy Problem For Inhomogeneous Transport Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, cauchy-problem, transport-equation

Here is a problem:

$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
2 u_{t}-u_{x}=f(t, x), \quad t>0 \\
\left.u\right|_{t=0}=\varphi(x)
\end{array}\right.$

**My solution**

$\frac{d t}{2}=\frac{d x}{-1}=\frac{d y}{f(x, c)}$

Find the first characteristic:

$\frac{d t}{2}=\frac{d x}{-1} \Rightarrow C_{1} = x+\frac{1}{2} t$

And the second one:

$\frac{d t}{2}=\frac{d u}{f(x, y)} \Rightarrow \frac{d u}{d t}=f\left(t, C_{1}-\frac{1}{2} t\right)$

And solution is a linear combination of them:

$u(x, t)=\varphi\left(C_{1}-\frac{1}{2} t\right)+\int_{0}^{t} f\left(s, C_{1}-\frac{1}{2} s\right) d s$

Am I right? If not, how to solve it correctly?

Comment: Substitute your solution in the initial PDE problem to check your result!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your result :

$$u(x, t)=\varphi\left(C_{1}-\frac{1}{2} t\right)+\int_{0}^{t} f\left(s, C_{1}-\frac{1}{2} s\right) d s$$
But I think that is not completely finished because in the final form of result $C_1$ depends on $x$ and $t$ :
$$u(x, t)=\varphi\left(x\right)+\int_{0}^{t} f\left(s, x+\frac{t-s}{2} \right) d s$$